# How to change app theme dynamically programmatically

Tags: android

How to change the App theme dynamically in android. I have an app with many users, when users log in, as per requirements I have to change the app theme dynamically.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried setTheme above setContentView

Answer (score 0):

Try this

styles.xml

```
<style name="lightTheme">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/LightStyledTextView</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/LightStyledOptionsMenu</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="darkTheme">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/DarkStyledTextView</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/DarkStyledOptionsMenu</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LightStyledTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DarkStyledTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Menu Styles-->
    <style name="LightStyledOptionsMenu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue_grey</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DarkStyledOptionsMenu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/blue_grey</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

create this in BaseActivity and call in onCreate method

```
public void updateTheme()
{
    if (Utility.getTheme(getApplicationContext()))
    {
        setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    }
    else
    {
        setTheme(R.style.lightTheme);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    }
}
```

Utility.java

```
public static void setTheme(Context context, boolean theme)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(context.getString(R.string.prefs_theme_key), theme).apply();
}

public static Boolean getTheme(Context context)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return prefs.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.prefs_theme_key), false);
}
```

and in any Activity use any component to change theme, in this case Switch

```
Switch darkModeSwitch = findViewById(R.id.darkModeSwitch);

    darkModeSwitch.setChecked(Utility.getTheme(this));

    darkModeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, checked) ->
    {
        Utility.setTheme(getApplicationContext(), checked);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. When color changes in backend, color of app theme should change dynamically in android studio

Comment: Can you please answer the above question

Comment: you can use custom Layout and change background color at runtime

Comment: A layout with 3 button and status bar, how to change that 3 buttons and status bar color dynamicallyaccording to the users

Comment: Extend Button and set Background Resource from preference